# WPF MVVM: ComboBox SelectedValue binding

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, mvvm

Due to feedback in comments, I have updated my question.

I am trying to sort and fill a `ComboBox` (`cbVehicle`) based on `SelectedValue`/Item in another `ComboBox` (`cbLicenseHolder`).
The binding to the properties is done with a `BindableCollection` (basically the same as an `ObservableCollection`).

Below you will see my `ViewModel`.

```
namespace Ridel.Hub.ViewModels {

    public class TripViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.StackNavigation {

        private readonly IWindowManager windowManager;

        private BindableCollection<LicenseHolder> _licenseHolders;
        public BindableCollection<LicenseHolder> LicenseHolders {

            get => _licenseHolders;
            set => SetAndNotify(ref this._licenseHolders, value);
        }

        private BindableCollection<License> _licenses;
        public BindableCollection<License> Licenses {

            get => _licenses;
            set => SetAndNotify(ref this._licenses, value);
        }

        #region Constructor
        public TripViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager) {

            this.windowManager = windowManager;
            LicenseHolders = new BindableCollection<LicenseHolder>();
            Licenses = new BindableCollection<License>();
        }
        #endregion // Constructor

        #region ComboBoxes

        public void FillComboBoxLicenseHolders() {

            try {

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.connectionString)) {

                    SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new();
                    sqlDA.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select Foretaksnavn from tblLicenseHolder", sqlCon);
                    sqlDA.Fill(ds);
                }

                DataTable dt = new();
                dt = ds.Tables[0];

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {

                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr = dt.Rows[i];
                    LicenseHolder licenseHolder = new();
                    licenseHolder.Foretaksnavn = dr["Foretaksnavn"].ToString();

                    LicenseHolders.Add(licenseHolder);
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
        }

        public void FillComboBoxLicenses() {

            Licenses.Clear();

            try {

                DataSet ds = new();

                using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.connectionString)) {

                    SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new();
                    sqlDA.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("fillLicensesComboBox", sqlCon);
                    sqlDA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Foretaksnavn", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CbLicenseHolderSelection.ToString();
                    sqlDA.Fill(ds);
                }

                DataTable dt = new();
                dt = ds.Tables[0];

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {

                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr = dt.Rows[i];
                    License license = new();
                    license.KjøretøyID = dr["KjøretøyID"].ToString();

                    Licenses.Add(license);
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
        }

        private string _cbLicenseHolderSelection;
        public string CbLicenseHolderSelection {

            get { return this._cbLicenseHolderSelection; }
            set { SetAndNotify(ref this._cbLicenseHolderSelection, value);

                if (value != null) {

                    FillComboBoxLicenses();
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see, I have two `BindableCollection`, one named `LicenseHolders`, the other named `Licenses`. `LicenseHolders` is bound to `cbLicenseHolder`, `Licenses` is bound to `cbVehicle`.

Also, you see that I have added my method; `FillComboBoxLicenses`, to the `CbLicenseHolderSelection` property, and in the XAML underneath, you will see that I have tried to bind the property to the `SelectedValue` of the `cbLicenseHolder`.

But I am obviously missing a piece of the picture here. cbVehicle is not being populated.

XAML below:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbLicenseHolder" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="204" Width="291"               
          ItemsSource="{Binding LicenseHolders, Mode=TwoWay}"                 
          Loaded="{s:Action FillComboBoxLicenseHolders}"    
          DisplayMemberPath="Foretaksnavn"
          SelectedValue="{Binding CbLicenseHolderSelection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          FontSize="12"
/>
        
<ComboBox Name="cbVehicle" Canvas.Left="381" Canvas.Top="204" Width="269"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Licenses, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="KjøretøyID"
          FontSize="12" 
          IsEnabled="True"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
/>
```

Both `LicenseHolder.cs` and `License.cs` has implemented `PropertyChangedBase`.
Their properties looks like this:

```
private string _foretaksnavn;
public string Foretaksnavn {
    get { return this._foretaksnavn; }
    set { SetAndNotify(ref this._foretaksnavn, value); }
}
```

`SetAndNotify` is a framework function - it does this:

> "Takes, by reference, a field, and its new value. If field != value,
> will set field = value and raise a PropertyChanged notification."

My `stored procedure`:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getLicense]
    @Foretaksnavn nvarchar(50)
AS 
SELECT tblLicense.ID, LøyvehaverID, KjøretøyID
FROM tblLicense
INNER JOIN tblLicenseHolder
ON tblLicense.LøyvehaverID = tblLicenseHolder.Foretaksnavn
WHERE tblLicense.LøyvehaverID = @Foretaksnavn
```

Comment: Side note: SQL operations don't belong in a ViewModel.

Comment: You can remove all that SQL code (keep questions short). We only need to know the list is not  coming up empty.

Comment: `Licenses` ought to be a BindingList and/or you need to call PropertChanged(nameof(Licenses)) after filling it.

Comment: Also please don't ask two questions in one. Ask two questions instead.

Comment: I suspect that you need to clear the Licenses first in FillComboboxLicenses, otherwise every time you select in combobox1, the list in combobox2 will grow.

Comment: I would recommend to create a question for each issue.

Comment: Essential details are missing for an answer: FillComboBoxLicenses method implementation, Licenses property declaration. Also, it is not clear that the Licenses collections used by the ComboBox and DataGrid are the same collection, or are they two different, but of the same name?

Comment: @EldHasp -- I will try to clarify. FillComboBoxLicenses is in the CbLicenseHolderSelection property. I have instantiated a collection by the same name (Licenses) in two different ViewModels, yes. As for Licenses property declariation, sorry, I am not quite sure what you mean. xx

Comment: @HenkHolterman, thank you, I will separate my questions into two. Licenses is a BindableCollection/ObservableCollection, I tried to add PropertyChanged(nameof(Licenses));, but I wasn't able to. I have not added the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. But the model classes where I hold all the properties, does have PropertyChangedBase interface.

Comment: What type of collection do these properties have?
If it's an ObservableCollection, is it property read-only?
Rather than writing in comments, you it's better to complete the code in your question. And what is the type of the collection of items in the LicenseHolders property?

Comment: @EldHasp, I have updated my question. I see you have just written an answer, I will read it now :-)

Comment: A little advice (not directly related to the question): remove the setters from properties with observable (Bindable) collections, that is, make the properties "read-only".
This will help you avoid some random mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this not as an answer, but as clarifying questions for a better understanding of the problem.
I just need some explanations that include the code, so I have to give them in the form of an answer.

1. Change the implementation of properties, method and bindings as follows and report the result:

```cs
private LicenseHolder _cbLicenseHolderSelection;
public LicenseHolder CbLicenseHolderSelection {

   get { return this._cbLicenseHolderSelection; }
   set { SetAndNotify(ref this._cbLicenseHolderSelection, value);

       if (value != null) {

           FillComboBoxLicenses();
       }
   }
}
```

```xml
<ComboBox Name="cbLicenseHolder" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="204" Width="291"               
          ItemsSource="{Binding LicenseHolders, Mode=TwoWay}"                 
          Loaded="{s:Action FillComboBoxLicenseHolders}"    
          DisplayMemberPath="Foretaksnavn"
          SelectedItem="{Binding CbLicenseHolderSelection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          FontSize="12"
/>
```

```cs
public ObservableCollection<License> Licenses {get;}
    = new ObservableCollection<License>();
```

```cs
public void FillComboBoxLicenses() {

    try {

        DataSet ds = new();

        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.connectionString)) {

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new();
            sqlDA.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("fillLicensesComboBox", sqlCon);
            sqlDA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlDA.SelectCommand
                     .Parameters
                     .Add("@Foretaksnavn", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            // It is necessary to specify a specific property for the Value.
                     .Value = CbLicenseHolderSelection.SomeProperty.ToString();
            sqlDA.Fill(ds);
        }

        DataTable dt = new();
        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        Licenses.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr = dt.Rows[i];
            License license = new();
            license.KjøretøyID = dr["KjøretøyID"].ToString();

            Licenses.Add(license);
        }

    } // On this line (after the for loop), set a breakpoint.

    catch (Exception ex) {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
}
```

Also tell how many items are in the Licenses collection after stopping in the FillComboBoxLicenses method on the line after the loop.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this informative reply!! I have done the changes you suggested, and when I run it with the break-point, there are in the Licenses collection two items, which correlates to my database for that particular entity, but they don't show up as the format they are in my database, but instead are listed as {Ridel.Hub.License}.

Comment: `{Ridel.Hub.License}` is the string representation of the type.
Where are they displayed like this? In a ComoboBox named "cbVehicle"?
If so, then you have incorrectly set the DisplayMemberPath.

Comment: Only when I debug and check the collection, it's loaded with the correct number of items, but just, as you say, 
the type . The ComboBox is still empty at runttime. I don't understand and can't make sense of it

Comment: Then, according to your code, it will be impossible to find the reason.
These can be: confusion in ViewModel instances, an error in the name of a property, binding errors, and much more.
If you can use the "Dynamic Visual Tree" and "Dynamic Property Browser", then you need to look through them Data Context, Element State, Binding Errors, etc.
If you do not know how to use them, then create an abbreviated Solution (be sure to exclude the database and replace it with a test code that returns some data).
Write it down on GitHub and give a link.
I'll see what the problem might be.